# Visual Studio - Static Library Compatibility (2008, 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, static-libraries, backwards-compatibility

I have a product that I ship with static libraries for use by third party integrators.  I have seen compatibility problems with other versions of VS so I was wondering if there is any info about library compatibility from 08 to 10 and vice versa?

This is with Standard Windows Libraries (no mfc) and not ATL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best information I can find says that there is no library compatibility between 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score 0):

you are using MFC as shared dll or using ATL?